# ImageMagick flatten image TIFF not working

Tags: php, imagemagick, tiff, imagick

I am trying to flatten (merge all layers) a TIF image that is having multiple layers.

I have tried with :

```
$file = "/path/to/file.tif";
$im = new Imagick( $file );
$im->setImageAlphaChannel(Imagick::ALPHACHANNEL_REMOVE);
$im = $im->mergeImageLayers(Imagick::LAYERMETHOD_FLATTEN);
```

I am using

- PHP 7.2
- Imagick module version : 3.4.3
- ImageMagick version : ImageMagick 7.0.8-11 Q16 x86_64 2018-09-08

I had tried with PSD file with the same code above and it worked for PSD file.

Comment: Please provide a sample TIFF that causes problems.

Comment: Please find the sample TIF image here - https://wetransfer.com/downloads/b09dd3936d49902a859055dd2216902620180913071328/82f5b4
The problem appears when I try to flatten TIF image and save it as TIF format.

Comment: Your first layer appears to be a flattened version anyway. Can you just use that? I mean open `YourImage.tif[0]` and save that as whatever you want?

Comment: I am unable to open the flattened first layer.
`$im = new Imagick();
$im->readImage( '/path/imgmgk.tif[0]' ); 
$im->writeImage( '/path/to/save/imamgk.tif' );
$im->clear();
$im->destroy();`

Please help me.

Comment: Mmmm! Please try this in Terminal to extract the first layer `magick imgmgk.tif[0] result.jpg`

Comment: Then try this in Terminal to get each of the layers and append them side-by-side into a long strip `magick imgmgk.tif -coalesce +append result.jpg`

Comment: Thanks,I had tried with the above and it seems it is creating JPG file. I want to flatten the TIFF file and store it back again in TIFF format.